# Derived functors and derivatives

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

When looking at derived functors of a non-exact functor (e.g., ext, tor, sheaf cohomology groups) I am struck by their similarity to derivatives of a non-constant function in that they are both regarded as higher order corrections to failure of exactness/constancy.

My question is: is this intuition justified? If so, what is the analogy and how far can it be pushed, even formalized? Can injective/projective resolutions of an object in an appropriate abelian category be regarded as its infinitesimal neighborhoods? Can one do some form of calculus or differential geometry in abelian categories?

To take a concrete example: the first derivative of a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be interpreted as giving its rate of change, and its zeros, critical points of $f$. Is there an analogous interpretation for functors?

Comment: This is not really what the "derived" in "derived functor" means. A much closer analogy is Goodwillie calculus: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Goodwillie+calculus

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I still don't really understand Goodwille calculus, but some of the terminology suggests that derived functors are not unrelated either.  For instance, people call the category of (parametrized) spectra the "tangent category" of the original one, which suggests that the action of a functor on spectra is somehow its "derivative", and at least in many cases (e.g. Ext, Tor, (co)homology, etc.) the classical derived functors can be identified with the homotopy groups of a corresponding functor on spectra (or chain complexes, a.k.a. $H R$-module spectra).